# How to define rgb color as a function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Hello everyone,

I am still not very familiar with LaTeX and I want to define a function that generates an RGB color depending on the input;

For example, let's say if the input parameter `x` is in `[0,100]`, I want to assign the color `{RGB,1:red,(1-x/100); green,(0+x/100); blue,1}`

Of course, I could just calculate the right color by hand but I would like to define a function, let's say `\myrgb{10}` which then automatically outputs the right color which I could use the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\bfseries,minimum size=0.6cm,
inner sep=0cm}]
  \node[main node] (1)[fill=\myrgb{13}] {1};
  \node[main node] (2)[fill=\myrgb{27}] {2};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How should I do that? Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are loading Ti*k*Z, why not compute your colours with `pgfmathparse`?

[image: textcolour with pgfmathparse]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\textcol}[2]{%
    \pgfmathparse{1-0.01*#1)}\edef\rcolor{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{0.01*#1)}\edef\gcolor{\pgfmathresult}%
    \definecolor{mycolour}{rgb}{\rcolor, \gcolor, 1}%
    \textcolor{mycolour}{#2}%
    }

\begin{document}
    Hello, my colour is \textcol{60}{very nice} in this text!
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

Since you wanted to fill a node, in the first place, here's a solution to do so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\tikzset{
  myfillrgb/.code args={#1}{
    \pgfmathparse{1-0.01*#1)}\edef\rcolor{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{0.01*#1)}\edef\gcolor{\pgfmathresult}%
    \definecolor{mycolour}{rgb}{\rcolor, \gcolor, 1}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour}
  }
}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\bfseries,minimum size=0.6cm,
    inner sep=0cm}]
        \node[main node,myfillrgb={10}] (1) {1};
        \node[right of = 1,main node,myfillrgb={50}] (2) {2};
        \node[right of = 2,main node,myfillrgb={90}] (3) {3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: node fill with pgfmathparse]

Comment: @Johannes I edited my answer with a solution to fill the nodes.

Comment: Wow, that's so awesome, thank you it works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done pretty straight forward using `xcolor`'s own capabilities (extended colour expressions in this case). The only thing missing is an expandable way to evaluate `100-#1`. If `#1` was always an integer we could simply use `\the\numexpr100-#1\relax`. But to be as versatile as possible the following uses `\fpeval` instead.

It defines a macro called `\myrgb` that can be used anywhere where `xcolor`expects a colour. As a small drawback, Ti*k*Z will not understand that `\myrgb{10}` is a colour, so if you want to change the stroke colour with `\myrgb` you'll have to use the `color` key.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\myrgb[1]
  {rgb,100:red,\fpeval{100-#1};green,\fpeval{#1};blue,100}

% compare the results of \myrgb with the direct usage of [rgb]
\newcommand\compare[1]
  {%
    \textcolor{\myrgb{#1}}{\rule{5pt}{5pt}}%
    \textcolor[rgb]{\fpeval{(100-#1)/100},\fpeval{(#1)/100},1}{\rule{5pt}{5pt}}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[color=\myrgb{100}, fill=\myrgb{0}, ultra thick] circle[radius=5pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\compare{0}

\compare{10}

\compare{20}

\compare{30}

\compare{40}

\compare{50}

\compare{60}

\compare{70}

\compare{80}

\compare{90}

\compare{100}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

One can use `newcommand`, `\newcommand{\colour}[1]{\color[RGB]{#1,#1,1}}`.

`red,green,blue`; the quantity of each color is represented with a number between 0 and 255.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\colour}[1]{\color[RGB]{#1,#1,1}}
\newcommand{\textcolour}[2]{\textcolor[RGB]{#1,#1,1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras erat orci,
{\colour{233}interdum vel est ac, posuere ullamcorper erat}. 
Proin condimentum, quam a convallis sagittis, est nunc egestas dui, a tincidunt metus enim in arcu. Morbi suscipit diam sodales mauris sodales vestibulum. Donec eget scelerisque lorem. Proin pellentesque nisi eget massa ullamcorper euismod. Donec nisi enim, dignissim pharetra sodales ac, mattis ac dolor. Mauris mauris nibh, maximus sed dolor vitae, scelerisque luctus mauris. Ut non finibus massa, sed faucibus leo. Curabitur condimentum magna id ultrices molestie. Curabitur consectetur sollicitudin ipsum. 
\textcolour{59}{Sed hendrerit, lectus quis egestas semper, odio odio condimentum nibh}, nec efficitur felis sapien vel diam.
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: But that doesn't create the color that I want, right? I'd need a color that requires a calculation, so for example if the input is 27, then I'd want /myrgb{27} to be red: 1-27/100= 73%, green 27% and blue 100%

Comment: I suppose you could do `\colour{73}{27}`, but then it doesn't seem to be saving you all that much over the original `\color[RGB]{73,27,1}`.